# Summing and discarding grouped variables

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of this form

```
familyid memberid year contract  months
    1       1     2000    1        12
    1       1     2001    1        12
    1       1     2002    1        12
    1       1     2003    1        12
    2       3     2000    2        12
    2       3     2001    2        12
    2       3     2002    2        12
    2       3     2003    2        12
    3       2     2000    1        5
    3       2     2000    2        5
    3       2     2001    1        12
    3       2     2002    1        12
    3       2     2003    1        12
    4       1     2000    2        12
    4       1     2001    2        12
    4       1     2002    2        12
    4       1     2003    2        12
    5       2     2000    1        8
    5       2     2001    1        12
    5       2     2002    1        12
    5       2     2003    1        4
    5       2     2003    1        6
```

I want back a dataframe like

```
   familyid memberid year contract  months
    1       1     2000    1        12
    1       1     2001    1        12
    1       1     2002    1        12
    1       1     2003    1        12
    2       3     2000    2        12
    2       3     2001    2        12
    2       3     2002    2        12
    2       3     2003    2        12
    4       1     2000    2        12
    4       1     2001    2        12
    4       1     2002    2        12
    4       1     2003    2        12
    5       2     2000    1        8
    5       2     2001    1        12
    5       2     2002    1        12
    **5       2     2003    1        10**
```

Basically I want to sum the variable months if they same familyid shows the same value for the variable "contract" (in my example I am summing 6 and 4 for familyid=5 in year=2003). However, I want also to discard familiids which show, during the same year, two different values for the variable contract (in my case I am discarding familyid=3 since it shows contract=1 and contract=2 in year=2000). For the other observations I want to keep things unchanged.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Thanks to anyone helping me.
Marco

Comment: It seems like `dplyr`'s use of `group_by` and `summarize` would work well here. Have you tried `dplyr`?

Comment: What should happen to `memberid` for those rows where you add the months? IN this example the last two rows happen to have the same memberid, is that always going to be the case?

Comment: To clarify, if a family has one occasion of multiple contracts in one year, you want to remove all rows for any years for that family?

Comment: @CalumYou Yes, memberid will be always the same during the same year. It can change accross years but, since we sum only cases of multiple contracts during the same year, this should not be a problem.

Comment: @JonSpring I want to remove all rows for any years for families which show different (in terms of type of contract, which in my data frame are represented by value 1 or 2) in one year. If a family has multiple contracts but of the same nature, I want to sum the months each contract lasted.

Comment: In your example you removed all lines for family 3, not just year 2000. Did you mean to keep their years 2001-03 lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned that you wanted to get the total months within one family's single contract in one year, but also to remove the families entirely with more than one contract in a year. Here's one approach:

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(familyid, memberid, year, contract) %>%
  summarize(months = sum(months, na.rm = T)) %>% 

  # We need this to answer the second part. How many contracts did this family have this year?
  mutate(contracts_this_yr = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%

  # Only include the families with no years of multiple contracts
  group_by(familyid, memberid) %>%
  filter(max(contracts_this_yr) < 2) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Output

```
df2
# A tibble: 16 x 5
   familyid memberid  year contract months
      <int>    <int> <int>    <int>  <int>
 1        1        1  2000        1     12
 2        1        1  2001        1     12
 3        1        1  2002        1     12
 4        1        1  2003        1     12
 5        2        3  2000        2     12
 6        2        3  2001        2     12
 7        2        3  2002        2     12
 8        2        3  2003        2     12
 9        4        1  2000        2     12
10        4        1  2001        2     12
11        4        1  2002        2     12
12        4        1  2003        2     12
13        5        2  2000        1      8
14        5        2  2001        1     12
15        5        2  2002        1     12
16        5        2  2003        1     10
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for! I was missing the second part actually... Thank you so much Jon.